# How to check if all ajax data loaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to set the determine height of all div's. But getting the wrong height value just because of ajax loading images taking some time to load. It's causing the wrong height value coming. Can you help me to get the actual height after ajax complete.

Ajax call:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/index.php?rest_route=/all/resources' + page_string + sort_string + business_param + search_string + all_filters + webinar + $scope.post_type
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.call();
}, function (error) {

    console.error('There was some problem in loading resources data.');
});
```

Height Determine Function:

```
$scope.call = function () {
    angular.element('.grid-item').each(function () {
        $height = angular.element(this).find(".text-wrap").outerHeight(true);
        angular.element("grid-item").css('height', $height + 'px');
    });
};
```

Image div is loading inside the `text-wrap` div. Please help me to get the actual height.

Comment: You can add load event to all the images and it will tell you when they are done loading

Comment: But inside that i am calling masonary library. That is causing issue with it. `$('.refresh-card-grid .grid').masonry($scope.masonryOptions);`

Comment: So did you search "masonry load event" maybe that can help you find previous questions

Comment: Yes i have searched. But i need to first set the determine height over all div's those are coming through `ng-repeat` and then apply masonary on it for visibility. All working fine except image load delay issue with actual div height.

Comment: So than the only option you have is to wait until all the images load, than apply it.... unless you set specific heights to the images.... So select the images, bind a load listener, than wait til they are all loaded.

Comment: It's works bro. Thank you so much!!